# Comparison of folders with Beyond Compare Script

Tags: beyondcompare, file-comparison, beyondcompare3

I would like to have a Beyond Compare script that compare the file contents of two folders and produce a text-report. How can I do this? Using the text-report only compares two files. The folder-report does not compare the file contents.

thanks

Answer (score 6):

myscript.txt

```
 load %1 %2
 expand all
 select all.files
 file-report layout:side-by-side options:display-mismatches output-to:%3
```

Now you can create a batch file and write something like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Beyond Compare 3\BComp.com" @myscript.txt file1.txt file2.txt Save.txt /silent
```

Answer (score 1):

First run this Command Prompt then use in application. You need to wrap the whole code in the double quotes.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Beyond Compare 4\BComp.exe" @C:\\SOPFiles\\1\\CompareReport.txt "C:\\SOPFiles\\1\\Master_Lead.docx" "C:\\SOPFiles\\1\\Lead2.docx" "C:\\SOPFiles\\1\\Lead2_comp.html"
```

The content of `CompareReport.txt` is:

```
file-report layout:side-by-side options:display-mismatches output-to:%3 output-options:html-color,wrap-word %1 %2
```